# How to get row number in this query

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have the following `WP_Query($arg)`:

```
$arg = array(
    'post_type' => 'ma_novel',
    'post_status'=>'fn_publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
```

That does this SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ma_rating')
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'fn_novel'
  AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

How do I get the **row number** of post ID `108` in above SQL query? It is in the `wp_posts` table.

Comment: This should be quite entry level stuff for someone who has SQL skills.

Comment: I wonder what the '1=1' filter clause is doing there...

Comment: @olleo Happy to remove it. :)